# Catch Data from a barcode scanner connected via Ethernet

Tags: vb.net, winforms, barcode-scanner, cognex

I have a vb.net application that needs to catch the readings from a barcode scanner in a TextBox.

As far as I know, the scanners work sending the data as keystrokes, but I don't know if that still applies when it's connected via Ethernet cable

Well, to get to the point, will the scanner send the data automatically to the textbox? or it will be necessary to work with sockets to handle the readings? and in that case, can some please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

-x-

In case you ask, the scanner is a COGNEX DATAMAN 500QL

Comment: "Will the scanner send the data automatically to the textbox"... Are you a programmer?

Comment: yeah, i'm a programmer. And yeah the scanner will send data automatically to the textbox to run some comparisons before doing other things, but i dont know if its handled in a different way because the connection is via Ethernet cable

Comment: Have you tested it already? Seems like the first logical thing to do

Comment: The thing is that i can't run tests on the form since the client who owns the scanner is in another state, but they ran some tests with the console with the same connection method

Comment: There are documents like this from 2010 [DataMan 500 Quick Reference Guide](https://files.rakurs.su/Sistemy-identifikaciy/Ustroystva-chteniya-verifikatsii-kodov/Cognex/DataMan-500/DataMan-500-Kratkoe-rukovodstvo-eng.pdf) [Cognex DataMan 500 Lector](https://www.mbcestore.com.mx/pdf/cognex/dataman-500.pdf), but it is not listed on the current site [FIXED-MOUNT BARCODE READERS](https://www.cognex.com/products/barcode-readers/fixed-mount-barcode-readers), so maybe it is no longer supported? You may need to contact the vendor to obtain documentation or SDKs for older products.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the software and drivers from their [support site](https://support.cognex.com/downloads/dataman/software-firmware)?